# How to get overflow exception in C++?

Tags: c++, debugging

What's the easiest way to catch an overflow exception in C++?

For example, when I'm writing something like

```
int a = 10000, b = 100000;
int c = a * b;
```

or (optionally)

```
std::cout << a * b;
```

I'd like to catch an exception (or notification). How to do so? Maybe there is any native solution for GNU C++, isn't there?

Comment: Standard C++ does not define arithmetic exceptions for integer math.

Comment: @DanielKamilKozar but... why?

Answer (score 2):

You do the following:

```
if (b > 0 && a > MAX_REPRESENTABLE_VALUE/b)
{
    throw your_exception("Message");
}
```

Note that `a > MAX_REPRESENTABLE_VALUE/b` is equivalent to `a*b > MAX_REPRESENTABLE_VALUE` mathematically but you have to use the former form if you are doing it with limited-precision arithmetic.

See the header `climits` for constants for `MAX_REPRESENTABLE_VALUE`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/

Comment: It's a good solution, but because I can't overload the `operator+` for standart types, it forces me to use own functions, like `add`, `mul`, etc.   But it is tiresome and it makes my code too complicated.

Comment: An alternative would be to create your own type which holds a single `int` and then overload `operator+` for that type.

Answer (score 1):

From the standard section 5 Expressions

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for its type, the behavior is undefined. [ Note: **most existing implementations of C++ ignore integer overflows**. Treatment of division by zero, forming a remainder using a zero divisor, and all floating point exceptions vary among machines, and is usually adjustable by a library function. —end note ]

**Emphasis mine.**

Comment: Note that unsigned integer overflow is well defined, however.

Comment: Rather unsigned integers do not overflow in the first place, making this text valid when considering them.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an exception, it's an error (if that pleases you). The reason is that arithmetic overflow cannot be determined before runtime. It is a runtime error subclassing from superclass `error`.

What you are looking for is arithmetic overflow.

Check out C++ documentation for `overflow_error` class [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/overflow_error/).

Comment: What are you getting at? `std::overflow_error` is meant to be thrown, and derives from `std::exception`. Regardless, it does not come into play at all in the OP's situation.